Горячие клавиши на Local History | Show History | Put label в Pycharm
Подскажите, есть ли горячие клавиши на  Local History | Show History | Put label в Pycharm ?
В документации написано, что доступ по правой кнопке мыши... может быть как то можно на кнопки поставить?

